# Qual o nome da barra inferior do Android e como manipulá-la?

Tags: java, android, layout

**No meu aplicativo eu removi o background do status bar com o seguinte código:**

```
Window g = getWindow();
        g.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

**Imagem da status bar:**

[image: status bar com fundo transparente, mas exibindo informações como horário, bateria, rede, etc.]

A status bar ficou com fundo transparente, mas exibindo informações como horário, bateria, rede, etc... Como eu gostaria.

**Mas este comando também removeu o background da barra de baixo:**

[image: barra inferior com fundo transparente, mas exibindo os três botões: back button, overview button e home button]

Vejam que a barra inferior do aplicativo ficou sem background, estendendo o layout até o fim da tela, mas exibindo os 3 botões: back button, overview button e home button.

**O que eu gostaria de saber:**

- O nome desta barra inferior (se tiver)
- Como mudar a cor dos 3 botões que aparecem em ali em baixo (se possível)
- Como posso adicionar esta barra de volta mas manter o status bar com fundo transparente

Answer (score -1):

O nome desta barra é "navigationBarColor".

Sobre deixar a status bar transparente, siga este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar
[image: Descrição dos componentes na tela]